# How to SET a heading for the select dropdown that query data from the database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm wondering if it is possible to SET a heading (i.e. Select Name)for the select dropdown that query data from the database. Many thanks

Current code:

```
<select>
<?php 
include("db.php";)
          $sql = SELECT * FROM Persons;
          $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          echo "<option value='" . $row['name'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</option>";}?>
           </select><br>
```

Desired effect

```
<select>
     <option value="default">Select Name</option>
         <option value="Tom">Tom</option>
     <option value="Mary">Mary</option>
     <option value="John">John</option>
           </select><br>
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What is "SET a heading"? What is "i.e. Select Name"?

Comment: sorry abt that, may be can you check out the code snippet

Comment: I did, still not clear... maybe it's just me

Comment: for the dropdown on the 1st row, I want to set a default heading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just prepend a `<option value="default">` to the other options:

```php
<select>
  <option value="default">Select Person</option> <!-- default option -->
  <?php 
  include("db.php";)
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM Persons";
  $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "  <option value='" . $row['name'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
  }
  ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Btw it wont allow me to accept yr answer until after 8 mins, will do so after that.